# Pine Script prior timeframe data during intraday

Tags: session

How do I request the server to provide the close of the fifth bar of the prior day without considering the current intraday session?  At the close of the fifth bar on today’s session (9:40 am), close[5] updates to the close from this session (and is set to this going forward for the rest of the day), but I want to return only the close of the 5th two-minute bar from yesterday.  I want to avoid querying the chart – this is for a metric used in a custom screener that looks at many symbols, hence my need to do this via a security request.

Any advice is much appreciated.

```
prior5 = request.security("TSLA", '2', close[5], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_off)
```